# How can i refer to an external function in an actionscript file - Flashbuilder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I hava a problem with flashbuilder:

I have a list with an itemrenderer that renders an image that (should be) draggable.
the rendered image refers to a function that is declared in an actionscript file: dragDrop.as in the folder AS.

the list:

```
<s:List id="imageList" width="139" height="438"
        dataProvider="{xmlListColl}"
        itemRenderer="itemRenderer.ImageRenderer"
        dragEnabled="true">

</s:List>
```

the itemrenderer renders this image and refers to the function doDrag:

```
<mx:Image width="100" height="70" maintainAspectRatio="true" 
          MouseDownEffect="AS.dragDrop.doDrag(event)"
          source="{data.@thumbnailImage}"/>
```

the function in dragDrop.as:

```
public function doDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var img:mx.controls.Image = event.currentTarget as mx.controls.Image;
        var dragImg:mx.controls.Image = new mx.controls.Image();
        dragImg.source = img.source;

        var dsource:DragSource = new DragSource();
        dsource.addData(img, 'img');

        DragManager.doDrag(img, dsource, event, dragImg);
    }
```

but it seems the function is never called...

also parentdocument and outerdocument don't seem to work (if i put the function in the document where the itemrenderer is called)

Please Help!

Comment: Do you have a script tag that includes the dragDrops.as file?

Comment: yes, indead: include "AS/dragDrop.as";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues here, but ultimately, you're not seeing a reference to that method, which means your dragDrop.as file is not including.

Here are a few suggestions:

1. Replace **MouseDownEffect** with **mouseDown**. Instead of causing an effect to occur,  you're now listening for the "MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN" event to fire. Differences between **effects** and **responding to events** are described here and, to quote, ["Behaviors let you add animation and motion to your application when some user or programmatic action occurs, where a behavior is a combination of a trigger paired with an effect. A trigger is an action, such as a mouse click on a component ... An effect is a visible or audible change to the target component that occurs over a period of time, measured in milliseconds."](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=createeffects_1.html)
2. Make sure you're including your **dragDrop.as** file. Flex 3 vs. Flex 4 handle **script** tags differently. If you're not including or importing your code, then of course it won't fire.
3. **include** vs **import** is a good question. You can "include" code that's a definition of methods, instances, constants, etc. But you would "import" defined classes for use. Since your method is a public function, does it live within a class? Or is it meant to just live in the script file, in which case you should remove the accessor "public"
4. If you're looking to implement Drag-and-Drop, I highly recommend NOT re-inventing the wheel and checking out what Adobe has already implemented for components, including **dragEnabled='true'** and **dragMoveEnabled='true'**. Check them out here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_4.html
   http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=dragdrop_1.html

Here is an example of a **Flex 3** script tag:

`<mx:Script source="AS/dragDrop.as"/>`

Here is an example of a **Flex 4** script tag:

```
<fx:Script source="AS/dragDrop.as"/>
```

This is an link to the documentation on how to include directly into a `<fx:Script>` tag the code you'd like: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf61c8a-7ff4.html

Comment: Replacing the mouseDownEffect with mouseDown worked. Now I have another problem: The rendered items can't be dragged out of the list... can I solve this or won't this simply work? (or should I open a new question)

Comment: Ok i solved it, just adding dragMoveEnabled="true" to the list did it :) Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Don't forget to setup "dropMoveEnabled" for any components that need to register the "drop" event.

Comment: setting up dragEnter="dragAccept(event)" and dragDrop="dragDrop(event)" at the component seem to also do the trick